# Hanging Paintings in a Line

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I am hanging ten paintings in a nice straight line. I don't want the Van Gogh to hang next to the DaVinci. I don't want the DaVinci to hang next to the Warhol. In how many ways can I hang my paintings?

I am thinking 10! ways to hang the paintings.  9! ways Van Gogh next to DaVinvi.  9! ways to hang the Davinci next to the Warhol.

So I'm thinking 10!-9!-9!, but what do I need to add to account for the duplicates I subtracted?

Comment: First, there are $2 \cdot 9!$ ways to hang the Van Gogh next to the Da Vinci! (For each of the $9!$ you counted, you can swap the positions of the Van Gogh and the Da Vinci). But yes, you have to add back some that you subtracted twice, in particular, the ones where the Van Gogh is next to the Da Vinci AND the Da Vinci is next to the Warhol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually $2\times 9!$ ways you can hang the Van Gogh by the DaVinci and $2\times9!$ ways to hang the DaVinci by the Warhol, so your starting point is $10!-4\cdot9!$.  But this double-counts the $2\times8!$ ways you can have the DaVinci *between* the Van Gogh and the Warhol.  So the proper count is $10!-4\cdot9!+2\cdot8!$.

(Note, blf gave essentially the same answer in a comment while I was composing this.)